# Teammate unable to push commit to shared Bitbucket repo using Git

Tags: git, bitbucket

A new team member joined recently and has been tasked with helping me on a project. She has been able to clone the repo, create her own branches, and push to the origin just fine until she got a new workstation recently. Suddenly, when she tries to push her commits, she gets the following error:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin Branch
remote: [POLICY] - #####################################################
remote: [POLICY] - Cannot push commits from other users
remote: [POLICY] - Current user is: username
remote: [POLICY] - Rejected Commit: name <name@company.com> (numbers)
remote: [POLICY] - #####################################################
To https://git.company.com:port/project.git
! [remote rejected] Branch -> Branch (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://username@git.company.com:port/project.git'
```

Why is this happening? She's trying to push and create a brand new branch, so it's not like she's trying to push to a preexisting branch that she doesn't have access to. Even still, she was able to push to master on her previous computer, so why is this suddenly happening now? I thought it was a certificate issue, so I had her delete her old one and authenticate again, but she still receives this error. The fact that she was previously able to commit to the repo means this also isn't a permissions issue.

Comment: You'll have to ask the people who maintain the pre-receive script for the corporate server for details. All of these messages are coming from their own code, not from anything that's part of Git.

Comment: @torek Thanks for the help, I didn't realize this was an admin issue. I'll have a talk with IT about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a pre-receive hook typically activated in a BitBucket Stash instance, as this [thread illustrates](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Pre-commit-hooks-in-Stash-3-7-0/qaq-p/263271).
That thread incorrectly mentions a pre-commit hook, but that would be a client-side hook. The `[remote]` part of the message points to a server-side hook.

The admin can log on the server and check what `$STASH_HOME/shared/data/repositores/REPO_ID/hooks` includes.